# JavaScript is not working in popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap popover in my application. JavaScript is not working in the popover element when i am using the first method.

**First method** ,Returning html content ,where the javscript element is not working on the popover element

```
$('#signInPopLink').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#signInPopover');
    }
  });
```

**Second method** ,Returning content by using selector (id)  ,where the JavaScript element is working on the popover element

```
$(function(){
      $('#signInPopLink').popover({ 
        html: true,
        content: function() {
        return $('#signInPopover');
        }
      }); 


    });
```

[demo for the second method](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Ddv/)

What is the problem with the first mehod ,please help me to understand.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: You are using id as selector in both cases. only difference is that the second script runs after page is ready.

Answer (score 3):

You first code is running when the elements are not present in the DOM.

So no event get attached as there is no element at that moment.

---

Your Second code is in [$( document ).ready())](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Which make sure the code runs after the DOM is ready .

> Note: `$(function() {` Shorthand for `$( document ).ready()`

Comment: i'm curios about the reason for down vote on this post?

Comment: -1 that you are saying first code is running. mistakenly understood ,, removed...

Comment: @C-link Never Mind :)

Answer (score 1):

`$(function(){});` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){});` So it's running But without this wouldn't.